# Подсчет количества скобок. Оптимизация

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Есть ли более альтернативный вариант проверки на количество?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool IsCorrect(const char* text, const int length)
{
    _STD vector<int> stack(0);

    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        if (text[index] == '[')
            stack.push_back(1);
        else if (text[index] == ']')
            if (!stack.empty())
                stack.pop_back();
            else
                return false;
    }

    return stack.empty();
}

int main(void)
{
    char text[] = "[Hello [[world]]]awdad";

    bool result = IsCorrect(text, strlen(text) - 1);
    _STD cout << (result ? "True" : "False") << _STD endl; // out True

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "более альтернативный вариант", это как? Сформулируйте задачу и претензии к текущему решению, пожалуйста

Comment: судя по коду, он не считает количество скобок вообще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть, конечно, более альтернативный вариант.

1. Вычислять длину текста в самой функции `IsCorrect`.
2. Использовать не вектор, а банальный `int`. +1 на открывающую скобку, -1 на закрывающую.